# Passing additional data with reference tokens in Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using reference tokens on my Identity Server and want to pass some additional data to the client.

I know how to do this with a JWT by setting claims in my Profile Service but I can't find a way to do something similar with reference tokens. Ideally I would like to pass my data as an extra parameter in the token json result like so:

```
{
    "access_token": "...",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "api1",
    "custom_property": "custom value"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement (and register) the `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` interface which could help adding custom response parameters :

```
public class DefaultClientClaimsAdder : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        context.Result.CustomResponse = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"hello", "world" }
        };

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Register it in `Startup.cs` in identity server app:

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomTokenRequestValidator, DefaultClientClaimsAdder>();
```

The custom property will include in token response :

[image]

Comment: This did it! Thanks a ton.