# IdentityServer4 with external provider. Redirect to frontend page with id_token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have configured IdentityServer4 with external providers like Facebook and Google. Also a have added default UI for Register, Login and other things. And my problem is how to redirect to the page with id_token?
Now my flow is:

1. Open `Identity/Account/Login`;
2. Click Facebook;
3. POST `/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin`
4. Redirect to `https://www.facebook.com/v4.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx`;
5. Redirect to `/signin-facebook?code=`
6. And now I'm redirected to `/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F&handler=Callback`

How to configure redirect from #5 step to specific page, not to `/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F&handler=Callback`?
I need it for my frontend to continue working with API via oidc-client.

I seen it in `Securing Angular Apps with OpenID and OAuth2` pluralsight course in 3.10 video, but Brian Noyes didn't use external provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps 2-6 are on Identity Server application , not your client app . When clicking Facebook login , user will be redirected to facebook's login page and enter the credential , facebook will return code(if using code flow) to identity server app , and then identity server app will send a post request to facebook's token endpoint with code for exchanging  id token/access token , after identity server app get id token , it will decode the token and get user's claims ,  then create identity server's own tokens and at last return to your client app .

Identity server will handle the external login in `ExternalLogin` method , you can't interrupt to return ID token to your client side during the authentication flow . If you need the facebook's ID token , you can cache the code in `ExternalLogin` method , and at last return to client app , for example , add token to token response . Check [this code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57603333/5751404) and check whether it helps.

**Updated :**

To get id token in `Callback` function of ExternalLogin , you can try below steps :

1. set `options.SaveTokens = true;` in `AddOpenIdConnect` config of Facebook login in Identity Server .
2. Use below codes in `Callback` function to get id token :

   ```
   var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

   var tokens = result.Properties.GetTokens();
   var idToken = tokens.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("id_token")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
   ```

Comment: And then how I can get id_token on frontend to continue working with API?

Comment: My purpose is to create post login page with #id_token=xxx, but on 6 step I'm redirected to page without id_token.